# How do I send HTML form data from a non-localhost client to the server?

Tags: php, html, apache

I started learning PHP yesterday, and I set up a little Apache server on my Ubuntu system.
Right now, my code is a bit scrambled, but I'll put it bellow:

### `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to leave a message</h1>
    <p>Welcome message: <?php echo readfile("prev_message.txt"); ?>
    <form action="form_handle.php" method="post">
        <p>Your message: <input type="text" name="message" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

### `form_handle.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Contact Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You've submitted your message for the next person</p>
        <?php
        $messagefile = fopen("prev_message.txt", "w") or die("Unable to save message!");
        $message = $_POST["name"];
        fwrite($messagefile, $message);
        fclose($myfile);
        ?>    
    </body>
</html>
```

When I use localhost to connect to the server, everything works as expected. The text you enter into the box is saved into a text file called `prev_message.txt`, and then when you reload `index.php`, the text entered is displayed fine.

For some reason however, when I connect to the same page via my IPV4 address on a laptop on the same network, submitting text does not work. The `index.php` displays the text written in the text file fine, however when I submit the text that I enter, the server end spits out a bunch of errors, and the text file is erased:

```
[Sun Aug 01 12:02:38.241279 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1218] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Aug 01 12:03:50.927608 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 1221] [client 192.168.1.85:57616] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/html/form_handle.php on line 11, referer: http://192.168.1.157/
[Sun Aug 01 12:03:50.927654 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 1221] [client 192.168.1.85:57616] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: myfile in /var/www/html/form_handle.php on line 13, referer: http://192.168.1.157/
[Sun Aug 01 12:03:50.927665 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 1221] [client 192.168.1.85:57616] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/form_handle.php on line 13, referer: http://192.168.1.157/
[Sun Aug 01 12:15:59.872866 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 1224] [client 192.168.1.85:57634] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/html/form_handle.php on line 11, referer: http://192.168.1.157/
[Sun Aug 01 12:15:59.872917 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 1224] [client 192.168.1.85:57634] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: myfile in /var/www/html/form_handle.php on line 13, referer: http://192.168.1.157/
[Sun Aug 01 12:15:59.872930 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 1224] [client 192.168.1.85:57634] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/form_handle.php on line 13, referer: http://192.168.1.157/
[Sun Aug 01 12:17:11.594541 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 3569] [client 192.168.1.85:57636] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/html/form_handle.php on line 11, referer: http://192.168.1.157/
[Sun Aug 01 12:17:11.594573 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 3569] [client 192.168.1.85:57636] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: myfile in /var/www/html/form_handle.php on line 13, referer: http://192.168.1.157/
[Sun Aug 01 12:17:11.594581 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 3569] [client 192.168.1.85:57636] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html
```

Let me know if more detail is required.

Comment: In your form you have name=message. So try $message = $_ POST["message"]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that  the variable  `$myfile` is not defined. Try to replace `fclose($myfile);` with `fclose($messagefile);`. Hope that fix it.

Comment: This wasn't the fix for what i was asking, but this is certainly a fix for the file not closing! Thank you very much.